# Tensorflow shows only "successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally" and nothing about cudnn

Tags: python, tensorflow

My tensorflow  only prints out the line:

`I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:152] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally` when running.

Tensorflow logs on the net has lots of other libraries being loaded like libcudnn.

As I think my installation performance is not optimal, I am trying to find out if it is because of this. Any help will be appreciated!

my tf is 1.13.1
NVIDIA Driver Version: 418.67
CUDA Version: 10.1  (I have also 10.0 installed. can this be the problem?)

Comment: What does nvidia-smi output?

Comment: the last line is from nvidia-smi

Answer (score 1):

According to `TensorFlow` [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu), `cuDNN` is a requirement for `tensorflow-gpu`. If you don't have `cuDNN` installed,  you wouldn't be able to install `tensorflow-gpu` since the dependency library would be missing.

So, if you have successfully installed `tensorflow-gpu` and are able to use it, e.g.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.Session()
```

you are fine.

**EDIT**

I just checker [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations) and `tensorflow_gpu-1.13.1` officially only supports `CUDA 10.0`. I would recommend to use it instead of `CUDA 10.1`.

Further, `NVIDIA` recommends using driver version `410.48` with `CUDA 10.0`. I would stick with it as well.

Comment: I know all this, and my system has both cudas installed because of this. However, the question was why I do not get all those load messages in my environment. its not only cudnn, its a bunch of other libraries as well

Comment: Why are you so sure that there should be those log messages? I just checked my system and I don't get them either. I am pretty sure that everything works on my end.

Comment: you can see in logs all over the place, like: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1046589/cuda-setup-and-installation/issues-with-tensorflow-on-cuda10-and-rtx2080/ (it fails afterwords, but you can see the cudnn loading message) or https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5537 (just search for the string). I am not sure it is wrong, might be something that appears only if you compile from source or something, but I want an authoritative answer.

Comment: You are completely right, it is weird that you (and me as well) are not getting those debug messages.
If you take a look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc) you will see that those messages should be printed for all libraries. In any case, they don't really mean a lot. If you want to be really sure, start a `TensorFlow` process and run following command `sudo pmap <PID> | grep cudnn` and you should see that your `cuDNN` library is correctly loaded.

Comment: Also, if you want to be *extra sure*, you can remove/rename `libcudnn*` from `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/` and `TF` will throw an error on loading.

Comment: I realize that it is probably nothing but it bothers my slight ocd enough to spend extra points on it....

Comment: My guess would be that tf wheel is built statically with these libraries so no need to dynamically load them (especially cudnn). However, i wonder if some of the optional libraries are just not found and not used and if there is a way to know that.

Comment: @Moshel I think that is a really good guess! If a library is loaded into the executable `pmap` will show it and it is being used.

Answer (score -1):

Actually i always rely on a stable setup. And i tried most of the tf - cuda - cudnn versions. But most stable was tf 1.9.0 , CUDA 9.0, Cudnn 7 for me. Used it for too long without a problem. You should give it a try if it suits you.

Comment: I had no stability problems with tf 1.13.1